# Spring Boot JPA Auto Reconfiguration on CloudFoundry/Pivotal Web Services

Tags: spring-data-jpa, cloud-foundry, spring-boot

I have a very basic spring boot application which uses MVC & data-jpa & posgresql. I bound a posgresql service to this application from Pivotal console. application.properties file has the local database information.

When I push the application to the cloud, it does not start giving "Connection Refused" errors from the JDBC driver. Which I think because it is trying the local database connection parameters. I thought auto-reconfiguration would change these parameters to the bound service ones. Anything else I need to do to get this feature?

Also, when I put the JDBC URL and credentials of the cloud service into `application.properties` and then push, its working. But not when I put them in `application-cloud.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the Java buildpack currently supports autoconfiguration of data source or enabling the "cloud" profile (the two fetaures that you are relying on). You can easily enable a profile using an environment variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). But you will need to ensure that Postgresql is in your classpath locally as well as on the remote platform for it to work.

Comment: That environment variable did the trick to activate the profile. But I'm not sure what to do for auto reconfiguration to work. (Not that I need it after your fix)

Comment: There's nothing you can do. Auto-reconfiguration is a CloudFoundry buildpack feature and I don't think it is enabled for Spring Boot apps yet. Wait long enough and it probably will be.